# Is it possible to make a page be viewed in different screens?

Tags: css, screen-resolution

I need a code that can change the layout of my homepage to be viewed in different PC monitors.
I already tried "responsive Webdesign", but I don't know if there is a way of making it be shown not just in different devices but also in different PC screen sizes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By 'responsive webdesign' I assume you mean media queries which in most tutorials are limited to `@media (max-width: ...) { ... }` or `@media (min-width: ...) { ... }` but there is actually a long list of features that you can query including `resolution` and `aspect-ratio` which seem particularly relevant to your question. A full list can be found on MDN : [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: If you want to see it in different browser sizes fast, then you can try out https://responsively.app/

Comment: It says its dangerous for my computer

Answer (score 0):

css's **media** tag is the one you might want to look into.

Quote from w3c [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

> The `@media` rule is used in media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices.
>
> Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:
>
> width and height of the viewport
>
> width and height of the device
>
> orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
>
> resolution
>
> Using media queries are a popular technique for delivering a tailored style sheet (responsive web design) to desktops, laptops, tablets, and mobile phones.

When you refer different PC monitor I assume you mean different width/length, or aspect ratio or resolution. I also assume your situation is that you want to show content in different style on different resolutions, but all on PC monitor, like 720p or 1080p or 4k monitors, following code might help.

```
/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, go from four columns to two columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll added it and I will test it now

Comment: This didn't work. I need 1024 x 768, my homepage have 3 navigation bars one left and right and the other one in the middle below the header.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by caoool, [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) is what you are looking for.
Basically, using media queries you can write custom css if the resolution is more or less than a specific value.

FYI, there is an awesome open-source css framework called [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) which makes designing responsive websites a lot easier and effortless.

Have a look at [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) and [Bootstrap Examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/) for more info about the framework.